# How to add row labels for a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I use the following code to color the numbers within my table like a heatmap

```
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                %
                \begingroup
                %
                % acquire the value before any number printer changed
                % it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % map that value:
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]
                {\value}
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}%
                % now, \pgfmathresult contains {<R>,<G>,<B>}
                % 
                % acquire the value AFTER any preprocessor or
                % typesetter (like number printer) worked on it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                %
                % tex-expansion control
                % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                            \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    }
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
color cells={min=-1,max=800},
col sep=&,  % specify the column separation character
row sep=\\, % specify the row separation character
columns/A/.style={string type} % specify the type of data in the designated column
]{
    A & B & C & D & E \\
    a & 10 & 10.1 & 100 & 11 \\
    b & 20 & 10.2 & 200 & 12 \\
    c & 30 & 10.3 & 300 & 13 \\
}
```

However, it expects all columns to be number, while I want to use labels for rows. It gives the following error:

````
Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'a' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'a'.. }```
````